# 7 Ubercart - Notify Customer Shipping when Product Ships

Tags: 7, ubercart, notifications, commerce

For our site, we process payments by performing a Capture on the PayPal site. Soon after, we pack and ship the order.

Does Ubercart provide a means for notifying the customer (via a button click somewhere in the admin site), via a pre-defined email, that the product has been shipped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a group box on each order detail page (e.g., admin/store/orders/123) which looks like the following:

```
Update order:
ADD AN ORDER COMMENT
[                     ]
```

After entering some text here (such as, "your order has been shipped"), clicking Update sends the notification to the customer via email.